# How to set scrollbar (using ScrollViewer) on top of my content?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, uiscrollview

I'm looking to add a scrollbar to a re-sizable window - I'm currently using ScrollViewer to do so. Both horizontal and vertical scrollbars appear but when the window becomes resized, both scrollbars go behind the window content. How can I set both horizontal and vertical scrollbars on top of the content?

Code Snippet:

`<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Views:TestingView Name="TestView" />
</ScrollViewer>
</Window>`

WindowStyle = ToolWindow and SizeToContent = WidthandHeight

Views is loading a research study poll page hosted by a 3rd party.

Screenshot of Window: [Scrollbar behind content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8OyR.png)

[Scrollbar behind content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIchP.png)

Comment: Try to use a `Grid` as container in `Window`, and put `ScrollViewer` in that `Grid`.

Comment: A ScrollViewer is a type of a grid that will only scroll the contents of it's nested child, perhaps the position of your scrollviewer is wrong, can you show the entire xaml code?

Comment: That's it, everything else is just xmls business. I'm aiming to keep this as simple as possible, if I can. @DarkTemplar

Comment: I did see the question and answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490784/how-to-place-a-scrollviewer-on-top-of-the-content-it-should-scroll

Comment: @AnjumSKhan thanks for the suggestion but I tried that earlier, same outcome